# Is there an equivalent method to java's `getDeclaredMethod()` to test private methods of classes in Typescript?

Tags: java, typescript, mocha.js, sinon

I'm unit testing a `typescript` project using `mocha` and `sinon`, with several private methods and variables. I have reworked by tests so that they are not calling them directly. I was wondering though, in unit testing I've done in `java` I've been able to use reflection to access private variables and methods. Namely, I've been able to use `java`'s `getDeclaredMethod()`. Is there an equivalent method in `typescript`? to test private methods of classes in `typescript`?

Comment: Are you talking about `private` or ECMAScript `#` private? In the former, you can easily access them outside the class if you do something like `(<any>object).somePrivate` since they are in reality regular properties in JS

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] so we can see something concrete?  Without an example you will either get general answers (e.g., use a type assertion) or someone will make up their own example as an answer and it might not fit your use case.

Comment: TypeScript has two completely different kinds of private methods and properties. (There is no such thing as a private variable, so that part of your question is unclear to me.) Which of the two are you talking about? Your question is basically un-answerable without a [mre].

Comment: Why test a private method? It's a good practice to go for [black-box tests](https://github.com/goldbergyoni/javascript-testing-best-practices#-%EF%B8%8F-14-stick-to-black-box-testing-test-only-public-methods), testing only your public methods.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript private methods are only private at compile time, so you can write code that accesses them and it will work. To silence the errors, you can put @ts-ignore on the preceding line

```
class Example {
  private foo() {}
}

const e = new Example();
// @ts-ignore
e.foo();
```

Alternatively, you can use a type assertion to get typescript to not do typechecks, as in:

```
const e = new Example();
(e as any).foo();
```